# "for" loop not working

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to isolate some values from a data frame
example:

```
test_df0<- data.frame('col1'= c('string1', 'string2', 'string1'),
'col2' = c('value1', 'value2', 'value3'),
'col3' = c('string3', 'string4', 'string3'))
```

I want to obtain a new dataframe with only unique strings from col1, and the relevant strings from col3 (which will be identical for rows with identical col1.
This is the loop I wrote, but I must be doing some blunt mistake:

```
test_df1<- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol= 2, nrow=0))
colnames(test_df1)<- c('col1', 'col3')
for (i in unique(test_df0$col1)){
  first_matching_row<- match(x = i, table = test_df0$col1)
  temp_df<-
    data.frame('col1'= i,
               'col3'= test_df0[first_matching_row, 'col3'])
  rbind(test_df1, temp_df)}
```

The resulting test_df1 though is empty. Cannot spot the mistake with the loop, I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Edit: the for loop is working, if its last line is `print(temp_df)` instead of the rbind command, I get the correct results. I am not sure why the rbind is not working

Comment: Does `test_df0[!duplicated(test_df0[["col1"]]), c("col1", "col3")]` do what you are looking for?  If so I can write it up as an answer and explain what it is doing.

Comment: Works like a charm! Do you mind to also explain why the loop is not working? thanks

Comment: @Istrel That won't work because the values of `col2` aren't the same.  you would have to do `test_df1 <- unique(test_df0[c("col1", "col3")])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier and faster way to do with is with the use of the `duplicated()` function.  `duplicated()` looks through and input vector and returns `TRUE` if that value has been seen at an earlier index in the vector.  For example:

```
> duplicated(c(0,0,0,1,2,3,0,3))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Because for the first value of `0` it hadn't seen one before, but for the next two it had.  The for `1`, `2`, and the first `3` it hadn't seen those numbers before, but it it had seen the last two numbers `0` and `3` previously.  This means that `!duplicated()` will return `TRUE` for the unique values of the data.

We can use this to index into the data frame to get the rows of `test_df0` with unique values of `col1` as follows:

```
test_df0[!duplicated(test_df0[["col1"]]), ]
```

But this returns all columns of the data frame.  If we just want `col1` and `col3` we can index into the columns as well using:

```
test_df0[!duplicated(test_df0[["col1"]]), c("col1", "col3")]
```

As for why the loop isn't working, as @Jacob mentions, you aren't assigning the value you are creating with `rbind` to a value, so the value you create disappears after the function call.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually assinging the rbind to anything! Presumably you need something like:

```
test_df1 <- rbind(test_df1, temp_df)
```

Comment: Thank you, it truly was a dumb mistake. i repeatedly read the script and couldn't spot it. Now, this is a conundrum! Barker gave me an elegant way to do the job, and you explained what the mistake was. Not sure which one of you should get the best answer! Thanks a lot